# datepicker issue while integrating using bower

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, bower

I am trying to integrate datepicker : https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker

I get following error:

```
 Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:

1) angular#1.2.14 which resolved to 1.2.14 and is required by angular-datepicker#1.0.14
2) angular#^1.3.0 which resolved to 1.4.5 and is required by h4h
3) angular#>=1.2.0 <1.5.0 which resolved to 1.4.5 and is required by angular-moment#0.10.3
4) angular#~1.4.x which resolved to 1.4.5 and is required by angular-modal-service#0.6.7
5) angular#1.4.5 which resolved to 1.4.5 and is required by angular-animate#1.4.5
```

Can you please suggest me what am I missing here ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular-datepicker#1.0.14 claims it depends on angular#1.2.14. However in your project, you are using angular#1.4.5.

you can try using angular#1.4.5 with datepicker 1.0.14 to see if the component is still working. If not, either downgrade your angular version (includes the other angular components, e.g. angular-animate) or try to fix the compatibility issue of datepicker to make it work on angular#1.4.5.